# Where can I find the official documentation of the limits of Google Custom Search Engine?

Tags: google-custom-search

Where can I find the official documentation of the limits of Google Custom Search Engine including for example the maximum number of synonyms?

I know I once saw a page listing various maxima, but now I (via Google) can't find it e.g. at

- https://cse.google.com/cse/docs/all
- https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=google+custom+search+engine+maximum+&oq=google+custom+search+engine+maximum
- https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=google+custom+search+engine+limits&oq=google+custom+search+engine+limits

Of course, the page I saw could have been withdrawn.

Answer (score 1):

The offical documentation is on https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/queries#limits

From the above link:

```
+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Item                             | Maximum allowed                 |
+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|  Number of search terms          | Multiple search terms, so long  |
|  (Synonym termelement)           | as the total number of variants |
|                                  | do not exceed 500 for each      |
|                                  | search engine.                  |
+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Number of variants               |                             10  |
| (Variant elements)               |                                 |
| for each search term             |                                 |
+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Total number of variants         |                            500  |
| (Variantelements) for the        |                                 |
| search engine                    |                                 |
+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| File size                        |                           500KB |
+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Number of files                  | As many as you need, so long    |
|                                  | as the aggregate size of all    |
|                                  | files in the account does not   |
|                                  |exceed 4MB                       |
+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Rubén. It looks like you were beaten by a few minutes. :) Number of synonyms was just an example. What I'm seeking is the list all limits.... on the reasonable assumption there are other limits.

Answer (score 0):

Some found here:

[image]

https://web.archive.org/web/20161124005200/https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/queries

(Body is now at least 30 characters; I had entered 17.)